# JSON Schema: Ignore required property if not defined in properties

Tags: json, jsonschema, angular6-json-schema-form

Any way to ignore a property being required if it does not exist in the `properties` definition?

For example:

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "billingAddress": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "isSameAsBillingAddress": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
    // Say I deleted the `mailingAddress` property
  },
  "required": [
    "billingAddress",
    "isSameAsBillingAddress",
    "mailingAddress" // ignore
  ]
}
```

From my understanding, this doesn't seem possible. I know this is kind of a silly question as someone may say to just remove the property name from the `required` array, but it becomes a bit more complicated when I am generating this JSON schema and also want to conditionally require a field if it exists.

For example:

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "billingAddress": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "isSameAsBillingAddress": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
    // Delete `mailingAddress` property
  },
  "required": [
    "billingAddress",
    "isSameAsBillingAddress"
  ],
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "isSameAsBillingAddress": {
          "enum": [true]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "isSameAsBillingAddress": {
          "enum": [false]
        }
      },
      // Would like to ignore...
      "required": ["mailingAddress"]
    },
  ]
}
```

Yes, I could write some code to go back and clean up this schema if the `mailingAddress` property gets deleted, but I was wonder if there was some JSON schema way of intelligently ignoring undefined `properties`?

Also from a JSON schema generator perspective, there just seems to be too many places a property name could be lurking, so any advice on how to structure this where code could easily clean up and generate a coherent JSON schema would be appreciated too.

Comment: This seems like something better suited to a schema linter -- to warn you that a property definition is missing and perhaps accidentally deleted.

Comment: @Ether I think your comment is definitely in the right direction, maybe make that the answer and I'll accept it. Unfortunately, there does not seem like very many linters available, at least not free and in the language I want: https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#schema-linter and https://www.json-schema-linter.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like something better suited to a schema linter -- to warn you that a property definition is missing and perhaps accidentally deleted.

You can find a list of linters here -- https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#schema-linter --
if this check isn't implemented yet, it is likely fairly easy to do so.

Answer (score 0):

no. `required` is intentionally independent of `properties`. `required` validates presence; `properties` validates child schemas *if* present.

> conditionally require a field if it exists

I'm confused by what this could mean - it feels backwards to the point of `required`. if you only require a field to exist when it exists, why have `required` at all?

maybe you just want to delete your `required` keywords altogether?

Comment: I mentioned I could and that would be the simplest way to get it to work, but please keep reading the question for the intent behind it. "if you only require a field to exist when it exists" is not what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't think that required property names that are not in properties should be ignored. See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.4.3

In your example mailingAddress must be present and its value can be any type because additionalProperties defaults to empty object which allows any type value in.

Comment: Agreed, I know this behavior is according to the specs. I was just wondering if there was a keyword or set up in the schema that WOULD ignore it.